# R Multiple Regression with Two Predictor Variables

Tags: r

I have a data.frame (X,Y,a,b,c,d,e)
Is there a package where I can predict both X and Y at the same time?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could try this answer on Cross-validated.
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11127/multivariate-multiple-regression-in-r

Comment: Yes, try Structural Equation Modelling with the package `sem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try package car, ?linearHypothesis, example

```
a multivariate linear model for repeated-measures data
see ?OBrienKaiser for a description of the data set used in this example.
```

However, it might not be appropriate for the real X Y you have.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Are the results better than doing two independent regressions?